# same address returned in C# struct pointer

Tags: c#, pointers, struct

I created a structure pointer, but each call for the new node returns the same address. But i expected different address to be returned for each invocation of the new node. Can someone please help?

```
public unsafe struct Node
{
    public int Data;
}
class TestPointer
{
    public unsafe Node* getNode(int i)
    {
        Node n = new Node();
        n.Data = i;
        Node* ptr = &n;
        return ptr;
    }
    public unsafe static void Main(String[] args)
    {
        TestPointer test = new TestPointer();
        Node* ptr1 = test.getNode(1);
        Node* ptr2 = test.getNode(2);
        if (ptr1->Data == ptr2->Data)
        {
            throw new Exception("Why?");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This code is almost the classic example for dangling pointers.

Comment: But the "new" had me fooled for a while too, before I looked at the IL-Code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't be fooled by the `Node n = new Node();` syntax! `Node` being a struct, `n` is allocated on the stack. You call `getNode` twice from the same function in the same environment, so naturally you are getting two pointers to the same stack location. What's more these pointers become invalid ('dangling') once `getNode` returns, because the stack location that belonged to `n` may be overwritten by a different call. In short: don't do it. If you want CLR to allocate memory, make `Node` a class.

Comment: Actually, my bad. I read the OP's post wrong. I thought he was returning the Node itself, not just the pointer. I took off my down vote, but someone else voted in the mean time...

Comment: @Mike Oh. Sorry then. BTW if he did return the Node itself, it wouldn't normally go on the heap, but into stack space allocated by caller.

Comment: Good answer! If you look at the generated code with ildasm you see that a heap object is never allocated and n is just local: ".locals init ([0] valuetype ConsoleApplication2.Program/Node n, ..."

Answer (score 0):

Is `n` getting garbage collected?

Comment: Nope. It's not on the heap but on the local stack.